# How to delete a question I posted?

Tags: support, questions

I want to delete a question which was posted by me a week before. How do I delete this or who can assist in deleting the question?

I have posted a question long time back and still couldn't able to get an answer. May be should I have to try in different place or would need to wait for some more time. Below is the link:

[Combining Always Encrypted AND Column level encryption in SQL Server 2016](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/187661/combining-always-encrypted-and-column-level-encryption-in-sql-server-2016)

That's the reason, have asked on how to delete.

Comment: I have added your comment clarification to the question and modified my answer below.

Answer (score 7):

Your question is answered in the Stack Exchange FAQ:

[How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

> > **You** can typically delete your own posts at will; for exceptions, see When can’t I delete my own post? below. To delete a post, just use the `delete` link below it.

---

> I have posted a question long time back and still couldn't able to get an answer.

It was only asked 12 days ago (at the time of writing). See [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)

> > To get better answers, you may need to put additional effort into your question. Edit your question to provide status and progress updates. Document your own continued efforts to answer your question. This will naturally bump your question to the homepage and get more people interested in it.
> >
> > If, despite your best efforts, you feel questions aren’t getting good answers, you can help by [offering a bounty](https://dba.stackexchange.com/helpcenter/bounty) on any question more than two days old.

Now you don't currently have enough reputation on this site to offer a bounty, but if you want to keep the question open for a while, I am happy to offer a bounty on your behalf. I haven't done this immediately because doing so would prevent you from deleting your question.

Comment: Thanks Paul for your detailed explanation. Appreciate your patience and support. I was looking for the answer little early in order to finalize the encryption approach for the project and all of other questions were answered in a day or two. Yes, please offer a bounty for the question so that it will add additional attention to the question.

Comment: Done, thanks...